# Upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, desktop won't wake up with mouse

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, suspend

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and now my desktop thinks it's a laptop and won't wake up from Suspend with mouse movement.  I have to re-boot to get computer working.  I did not have this issue with 14.04, so there's something in the upgrade messing up my computer.  What can I do?

Comment: What happens when you press keys on your keyboard?

Comment: Nothing, using any number of single keys or key combinations.  If I Suspend manually, I can wake it manually by pressing the Power button, if I let it Suspend automatically, I have to re-boot to get it going again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you test with disabling pwd-saving features?

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

To undo for command above:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

When PC goes to suspend, is it responding to caps lock ie. will caps lock illuminate caps lock led on keyboard?